# Texshop typing very slow in Sierra

Tags: mac, mactex

I've just bought a new MacBook Pro, loaded with MacOs Sierra 10.12.1. I downloaded the most recent version of TexShop (3.77) but I am finding that, when I am typing in the editor, there is an annoying and substantial delay between my key strokes and when the words appear on the screen. Otherwise things work fine. I don't have this problem in any other applications, or in other tex editors like texstudio. Any idea what is going on?

Thanks.

EDIT: This problem seemed to go away when I re-installed Texshop, but it has come back now. I tried changing fonts, as suggested below, but this didn't help.

Comment: I'm seeing no such slowdown. Try changing the font used in the editor to see if that changes anything. (Just a guess.)

Comment: Uhm, try reinstalling the application again. I think this is more an application-related bug than a TeX/LaTeX question… ps: TeXShop works fine for me

Comment: @ilFuria Questions about TeX/LaTeX related applications such as editors are absolutely on topic here, especially if the editor is a TeX/LaTeX IDE such as TeXShop.

Comment: Ok many thanks I reinstalled and the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reinstallation solved the problem.

Comment: @Vendler I think this will be a difficult problem to diagnose on a site like Stack Exchange. It might be better to contact Dick Koch (the main developer of TeXShop) directly.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you still on Sierra 10.12.1? The latest version, which has been out for several weeks at least, is 10.12.3.

Comment: Yes, TexShop is very slow with large files on High Sierra. I had the same TexShop set up on my old computer and the typing was fine even with large files. It is so bad I am not really able to use TexShop for serious work in my new computer.